# How to place an UIImage at the top centre using storyboard and auotlayout?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, xcode8

What are the constraints need to place an UIImageView at the top centre of the storyboard using auto-layout?
1.Currently i am setting Leading Space
2.Trailing Space
3.Width and height constraints
But the image displaces while coming in the 5s phone. Please help.

[image: FJ is the image view]

Comment: Width, height, top, and center horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly there. The leading and trailing constraints are the ones causing the issue. Remove both of those and then add the ['Center Horizontally in Container'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrSR2.jpg) constraint to UIImageView.

Hopefully that achieves what you are after.

Comment: Yep, because you have a width and height, the top and center horizontally can determine all the required points. If you didn't have the width and height then you would need more constraints.

Comment: Thanks..it solved...So why the leading and trailing causing problem??

Comment: I assume the leading and trailing constraints are fixed values so when you have a different sized screen, those fixed values would be different if you want the width of the image view to be the same. So due to the mismatch, Xcode will automatically break one of the constraints so the app doesn't crash.